# Max Nbr of Months W/ No Activity in Past 12 Months

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a data set that contains the following items:

1. Month-Yr
2. Account Nbr
3. Revenue Total

If an account does not have a revenue total for a given month there is no record for that account / month.

I would like to know per account - what is the maximum # of consecutive months that account had no revenue for?

For example if account 123 had revenue in every month in the last 12 their count would be 0.

If account 987 had revenue for 4 consecutive months then no revenue for 5 consecutive months and then revenue for the remaining months their count would be 5.

If account 657 had activity every other month then their count would be 1, b/c 1 is the max # of consecutive months with no activity.

Thanks in advance

SAMPLE DATA

```
**Accnt**  |**Month-Yr**   |**Revenue**
123        |8/1/2016       |1000
123        |9/1/2016       |1500
123        |10/1/2016      |500
123        |11/1/2016      |100
123        |12/1/2016      |250
123        |1/1/2017       |750
123        |2/1/2017       |900
123        |3/1/2017       |700
123        |4/1/2017       |1200
123        |5/1/2017       |250
123        |6/1/2017       |750
123        |7/1/2017       |900
123        |8/1/2017       |700
123        |9/1/2017       |1200
987        |8/1/2016       |100
987        |9/1/2016       |250
987        |10/1/2016      |750
987        |11/1/2016      |900
987        |5/1/2017       |700
987        |6/1/2017       |1300
987        |7/1/2017       |250
987        |8/1/2017       |750
987        |9/1/2017       |900
657        |8/1/2016       |700
657        |10/1/2016      |1200
657        |12/1/2016      |100
657        |2/1/2017       |250
657        |4/1/2017       |750
657        |6/1/2017       |900
657        |8/1/2017       |700
```

---

```
Accnt 123 would be 0 months
Accnt 987 would be 5 months
Accnt 657 would be 1 month
```

Comment: I think you would get more answers if you include some sample data and expected result

Comment: And the code/query you wrote that isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one? (Because you posted minimal info, I reserve the right to create my own DDL as I interpret).

```
    IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #sales
    GO 
    CREATE TABLE #sales
        (Dte datetime
        ,amt int
        ,id int
        ,rownum int identity PRIMARY KEY
        )   

    INSERT INTO #sales
    SELECT '9/1/17',1200, 987
    INSERT INTO #sales
    SELECT '10/1/17',1100, 987
    INSERT INTO #sales
    SELECT '11/1/17',1000, 987
    INSERT INTO #sales
    SELECT '5/1/18',1900, 987
    INSERT INTO #sales
    SELECT '6/1/18',120, 987

    INSERT INTO #sales
    SELECT '4/1/17',100, 657
    INSERT INTO #sales
    SELECT '5/1/17',190, 657
    INSERT INTO #sales
    SELECT '7/1/17',12, 657

    GO

    SELECT MAX(DATEDIFF(dd,a.dte,b.dte)), a.id
    FROM #sales a
    INNER JOIN #sales b
        ON a.rownum = b.rownum-1
        AND a.id =b.id
    GROUP BY a.id
```